# Application not running fullscreen on Tablet

Tags: android

am new to android. I am developing this application but it cannot run on the full screen mode of a Tablet.please check out my manifest file and advice whats missing or wrongly placed

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".LoginAtivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Select_CountryActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Main_menuActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="sold_pendingActivity"></activity>                       

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<supports-screens 
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens = "true"
    android:normalScreens = "true"
    android:largeScreens = "true"
    android:xlargeScreens ="true"
    android:anyDensity = "true"/>
```

Comment: put your mail.xml file also code snippet for LoginActivity

Comment: thanks Sumant, the problem was actually on the xml file. layout dimension was specified in px instead of dp...thanks for the eye opener

Answer (score 1):

In your `Layout.xml` u should set Parent `layout's width and height` to be `fill_parent`

Comment: Thanks guys for the effort. I got the solution. I had specified my xml layout dimension in pixels(px) instead of density independent pixels(dp). I appreciate the effort.